# Post data and file to REST-API with ContentType "multipart/mixed"

Tags: delphi, indy

I am using TidHTTP component in Delphi XE8. I already did a lot of research which brought me to this point, because TREST-components did not do the job also.

```
    ...
    RequestStream := TStringStream.Create(JSON.ToString, TEncoding.UTF8);
    Params := TIdMultipartFormDataStream.Create;
    try
      Params.AddFormField( 'documentmetadata', 'application/json', 'utf-8', RequestStream);
      Params.AddFile('content', FilePath, GetMIMETypeFromFile(FilePath));

      FidHttp.Post(url, Params);
    finally
      RequestStream.Free;
      Params.Free;
    end;
    ...
```

What I need to do is to post data and file with content type "multipart/mixed". Unfortunately TIdMultipartFormDataStream always creates "multipart/form-data", which is not accepted by the 3rd party REST API.

Is there an alternative way for doing this? Does somebody know a way for overriding the content type?

Regards,
Jan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TIdMultipartFormDataStream` is specifically designed for `multipart/form-data` only (hence its name), and as such, passing a `TIdMultipartFormDataStream` to `TIdHTTP.Post()` hard-codes the `TIdHTTP.Request.ContentType` to `multipart/form-data`.  There is no option to overwrite that <sup>1</sup>.

To do what you want, you will have to manually produce your own MIME data and store it in a `TStream` of your choosing *other than* `TIdMultipartFormDataStream` (such as `TMemoryStream`), and then you can `Post()` that stream with whatever `TIdHTTP.Request.ContentType` you want.  For example:

```
PostStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
try
  // you may have to tweak this based on your REST provider's actual requirements...
  WriteStringToStream(PostStream, '----myboundary' + EOL);
  WriteStringToStream(PostStream, 'Content-Type: application/json; charset="utf-8"; name="documentmetadata"' + EOL);
  WriteStringToStream(PostStream, EOL);
  WriteStringToStream(PostStream, JSON.ToString, IndyTextEncoding_UTF8);
  WriteStringToStream(PostStream, EOL + '----myboundary' + EOL);
  WriteStringToStream(PostStream, 'Content-Type: ' + GetMIMETypeFromFile(FilePath) + '; name="content"' + EOL);
  WriteStringToStream(PostStream, 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' + ExtractFileName(FilePath) + '"' + EOL);
  WriteStringToStream(PostStream, EOL);
  FS := TFileStream.Create(FilePath, fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyWrite);
  try
    PostStream.CopyFrom(FS, 0);
  finally
    FS.Free;
  end;
  WriteStringToStream(PostStream, EOL + '----myboundary--' + EOL);
  PostStream.Position := 0;

  FidHttp.Request.ContentType := 'multipart/mixed; boundary="--myboundary"';

  FidHttp.Post(url, PostStream);
finally
  PostStream.Free;
end;
```

<sup>1: That being said, I have experimented with adding support for a user-defined `ContentType` in `TIdMultipartFormDataStream`, but that is not checked in to Indy's main codeline at this time.</sup>